# How to get callback data outside of a function (AWS SDK)(non async)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that gets data from AWS:

**main.js**

```js
const { GetInstancesByName } = require("./functions");


var operationmode = "getinstances";

if (operationmode == "getinstances") {
  let getresult = GetInstancesByName(instance);
  console.log("(getinstances log)",getresult);
  let resultsent = "yes";
  callback(getresult);
}
```

then this is the functions file (functions.js):

**functions.js**

```js
const GetInstancesByName = function GetInstancesByName(name) {
    
  let ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});
  //console.log(ec2);

  let params = {
    Filters: [
      {
        Name: "tag:Name", 
        Values: [
          name
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
 
  ec2.describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) 
      console.log("error",err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else return data;                      // successful response
      /*
      data = {
      }
      */
  });

  return data;
};
```

I am trying to get the data from the (error , data) in the function. I have tried: setting a var/const/let to the data. the return data at the bottom works but data is empty. I want to get data so I can pass it back in the GetInstancesByName (being used by main.js).

on the main both `console.log("(getinstances log)",getresult)` and `callback(getresult);` both return not defined.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use async/await, you may pass a callback to `GetInstancesByName` as follows:

```js
function GetInstancesByName (name, callback) {

    // ...

    ec2.describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) { 
            console.log("error",err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        } else {
            callback(data);                      // successful response
        }
    });

    // ...
}

// In main.js
GetInstancesByName(instance, data => { 
    // do something with data
});
```

Comment: than, you very much for the reply